# How to restore WordPress backup?

Tags: wordpress, backup, posts

Three years ago, I owned a WordPress blog. I used to have around 1000 posts, but I decided to close it.

Now, I have new ideas and I would like to open a similar website with the same niche market. I still have the directory backup of the WordPress tree (but not the MySQL database). The name of the website will be different.

Is there any way to recover all the posts from this backup and insert into the new WordPress blog ?

Comment: yes you can import it.If that time you have backup plugins

Comment: if you dont have the mysql backup or the live site, you wont be able to do so. the theme contains only the template files so you're kinda stuck with the database part of it.